# Python gensim create word2vec model from vectors (in ndarray)

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a ndarray with words and their corresponding vector (with the size of 100 per word).
For example:

```
Computer 0.11 0.41 ... 0.56
Ball     0.31 0.87 ... 0.32
```

And so on.

I want to create a word2vec model from it:

```
model = load_from_ndarray(arr)
```

How can it be done? I saw

> KeyedVectors

but it only takes file and not array

Comment: what is the problem with saving those to a file and then reading it again with `KeyedVector` ?

Comment: @VnC I get an error: UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xd7'. The words are in hebrew so I guess there are encoding issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
words = myarray[:,0]
vectors = myarray[:,1:]
model = KeyedVectors(vectors.shape[1])
model.add(words, vectors)
```

if you want you can then save it

```
model.save('mymodel')
```

and later just load it

```
model = KeyedVectors.load('mymodel')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no existing convenience methods to turn your own array/word-list into a `KeyedVectors`. So you'd have to hand-construct that, in your own code.

But it's a pretty simple object, mainly one raw array and a dict for mapping words to index-locations, and all the source is available:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py

I would especially suggest strategies of doing one or both of:

- taking a close look at the `load_word2vec_format()` method including the similarly-named supporting function in the sibling `base_any2vec.py` file, and seeing each of the steps they use in reading a file and constructing a full instance
- training up a dummy `KeyedVectors` in one of the supported ways – such as by training `Word2Vec` on some synthetic corpus that includes exactly the words you need – and then either inspecting that object to understand the necessary parts of a working instance, or mutating that instance in-place to then have the vector-mappings you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example for something similar?

Comment: The only example code I can think of is that for `load_word2vec_format()` and `_load_word2vec_format()`.